# How do I remove almost-duplicate integers from list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm parsing some PDFs in Python. These PDFs are visually organized into rows and columns. The pdftohtml script converts these PDFs to an XML format, full of loose `<text>` tags which don't have any hierarchy. My code then needs to sort these `<text>` tags back into rows.

Since each `<text>` tag has attributes like "top" or "left" coordinates, I wrote code to append `<text>` items with the same "top" coordinate to a list. This list is effectively one row.

My code first iterates over the page, finds all unique "top" values, and appends them to a tops list. Then it iterates over this tops list. For each unique top value, it searches for all  items that have that "top" value and adds them to a row list.

```
for side in page:
    tops = list( set( [ d['top'] for d in side ] ) )
    tops.sort()
    for top in tops:
        row = []
        for blob in side:
            if int(blob['top']) == int(top):
                row.append(blob)
        rows.append(row)
```

This code works great for the majority of the PDFs I'm parsing. But there are cases where items which are on the same row have *slightly* different top values, off by one or two.

I'm trying to adapt my code to become a bit fuzzier.

The comparison at the bottom seems easy enough to fix. Something like this:

```
        for blob in side:
            rangeLower = int(top) - 2
            rangeUpper = int(top) + 2
            thisTop = int(blob['top'])
            if rangeLower <= thisTop <= rangeUpper :
                row.append(blob)
```

But the list of unique top values that I create first is a problem. The code I use is

```
    tops = list( set( [ d['top'] for d in side ] ) )
```

In these edge cases, I end up with a list like:

```
[925, 946, 966, 995, 996, 1015, 1035]
```

How could I adapt that code to avoid having "995" and "996" in the list? I want to ensure I end up with just one value when integers are within 1 or 2 of each other.

Comment: in the event you'd have `1,2,3,4,5` in your list, which ones would you choose? 1 and 4 ? 1 and 5 ? 2 and 5 ? 3?

Comment: In the PDFs I'm parsing, rows are consistently spaced at least 20 units apart, so I don't think I would end up with such a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Sort the list to put the close values next to one another
- Use `reduce` to filter the value depending on the previous value

Code:

```
>>> tops = [925, 946, 966, 995, 996, 1015, 1035]
>>> threshold = 2
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if len(x) == 0 or y > x[-1] + threshold else x, sorted(tops), [])
[925, 946, 966, 995, 1015, 1035]
```

With several contiguous values:

```
>>> tops = range(10)
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if len(x) == 0 or y > x[-1] + threshold else x, sorted(tops), [])
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

### Edit

Reduce can be a little cumbersome to read, so here is a more straightforward approach:

```
res = []
for item in sorted(tops):
    if len(res) == 0 or item > res[-1] + threshold:
        res.append(item)
```

Comment: Can you walk me through the reduce() line in your first code sample? That looks like what I need, I just want to understand what's going on.

Comment: reduce works like this. It takes a first value (in this case the last parameter, `[]` empty list), then calls the lambda with x being that value, and y being the first value of the list. It then repeats the call with x being the result of the previous call, and y the next item in the list. It returns the final result. For example, `reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y], tops, [])` makes a copy of `tops`

Comment: The content of the test in the lambda only appends `y` if it is greater than the previous element + threshold. This condition is sufficient because the list is monotonically growing. (`len(x) == 0` is added to the test to account for the first iteration.)

Comment: the `a if condition else b` is the ternary notation in python. It returns a if the condition is true or b if the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

@njzk2's answer works too, but this function actually shows what is going on and is easier to understand:

```
>>> def sort(list):
...     list.sort() #sorts in ascending order
...     x = range(0, len(list), 1) #gets range
...     x.reverse() #reverses
...     for k in x:
...             if list[k]-1 == list[k-1]: #if the list value -1 is equal to the next,
...                     del(list[k-1])     #remove it
...     return list #return
... 
>>> tops = [925, 946, 966, 995, 996, 1015, 1035]
>>> sort(tops)
[925, 946, 966, 996, 1015, 1035]
>>>
```

Comment: `del(list[k-1])` is highly unefficient. You don't need to `reverse`, just use `range(len(tops) -1, -1, -1)`. If you are going to use `reverse`, use `reversed`, which returns an iterator, rather than performing the complete in place reversal process. The question mentions `within 1 or 2 of each other`, so 1 is insufficient.

Comment: also, you are iterating on 1 too many item, as k goes as low as 0. (which will return an empty list if you test for equal items and all items are equal)

Comment: also, you really should never name a list `list`

Comment: also, this modifies (in-place sort) the input list. It may not be a wanted effect. (although the function name does say `sort`)