# Why doesn't del do the same thing?

Tags: python, append, del

Why does the following code change both variables:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> a.append(9)
>>> a
[9]
>>> b
[9]
>>>
```

But the `del` statement does not achieve the same effect?

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> del(a)
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> b
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Please do not keep creating the python-del tag with a tag wiki you wrote without having any idea what `del` does. It doesn't delete objects, and it didn't need a new tag to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
a = b
```

What you're doing is assigning the label `b` to the same object that the label `a` is refering to.

When you do:

```
a.append(9)
```

You're adding `9` to the list object pointed to by both `a` and `b`. It's the same object, so they show the same result.

When you do:

```
del a
```

You're deleting the *reference* to the object, not the object itself. If it's the *only* reference, then the object will be garbage collected. But in your case, there's another reference - `b` - so the object continues to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "variables", think in terms of names and objects.

```
>>> a = []
```

This makes an empty list object and binds the name `a` to it.

```
>>> b = a
```

This simply says that `b` is now a new name for the object named by `a`.  We have

```
>>> a is b
True
```

`del a` means that we're forgetting the name `a`: it is no longer bound to an object.

```
>>> del a
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-60b725f10c9c>", line 1, in <module>
    a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

But that you're no longer calling that list object `a`, only `b`, doesn't affect the object itself in any way.  Objects don't care, or even know about, what names you've given them.  [One semi-exception is that if an object no longer has any references, it may -- or may not, no promises -- be garbage-collected.]

Answer (score 0):

The `append` method works against the actual object, while `del` works against the reference i.e. variable name.

Answer (score 0):

(I already answered the question in [the other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331419/is-the-use-of-del-bad), so I'm going to use it here as well, with slight modifications:)

`del` does not delete objects; in fact in Python, it is not even possible to tell the interpreter/VM to remove an object from memory because Python is a garbage collected language (like Java, C#, Ruby, Haskell etc).

Instead, what `del` does when called on a variable (as opposed to a dictionary key or list item) like this:

```
del a
```

is that it *only* removes the local (or global) variable *not* what it points to (every variable in Python holds a pointer/reference to its contents not the content itself). In fact, since locals and globals are stored as a dictionary under the hood (see `locals()` and `globals()`), `del a` is equivalent to:

```
del locals()['a']
```

(or `del globals()['a']` when applied to a global.)

so if you have:

```
a = []
b = a
```

you're making a list, storing a reference to it in `a` and then copying that reference into `b` without copying/touching the list object itself. Therefore these two calls affect one and the same object:

```
>>> a.append(1)
>>> b.append(2)
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> a is b  # would be False for 2 identical but different list objects
True
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

(`id` returns the memory address of an object)

whereas deleting `b` is in no way related to touching what `b` points to:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> del b  # a is still untouched and points to a list
>>> b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>> a
[]
```