# Creating a list with two different numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 numbers `x` and `y`.
`x` for example is 1.5, and `y` is 1.5
I need to create a list of lists with 8 different values.

```
[[0.5,0.5],[0.5,1.5],[0.5,2.5],
[1.5,0.5],[1.5,1.5],[1.5,2.5],
[2.5,0.5],[2.5,1.5],[2.5,2.5]]

[1.5,1.5] #needs to be removed from the above list.
```

How can I do this in python 3 using different x and y values?
`x` and `y` will always be numbers between 1 and 10. But they will be 1.5 or 2.5 or 3.5 etc.

Comment: Can x and y be any floating point number as long as it's between 1 and 10? ie. 2.452, 2.01, 6.42. Or will it only ever be .5?

Comment: it's only ever ends with a .5

Comment: So you have a list of [x, y], and you want to remove that list from the list of lists, but only if x and y are the same?

Comment: `[[x,y] for x,y in l if not x == y]`

Comment: I want to make the top list the one with a len of 9. But, the list [x,y] where x and y are the variables x and y, i want gone. So its a list of len 8. And, no x and y can be different. for eg. x may = 4.5 while y may equal 2.5

Comment: You probably shouldn't have described the removal conditions as "When x and y are the same" in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following list comprehension:

```
items = [[a, b] for a in items for b in items if x != a or y != b]
```

As such:

```
>>> x = 1.5
>>> y = 1.5
>>> items = [x-1, x, x+1]
>>> items = [[a, b] for a in items for b in items if x != a or y != b]
>>> items 
[[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 1.5], [0.5, 2.5], [1.5, 0.5], [1.5, 2.5], [2.5, 0.5], [2.5, 1.5], [2.5, 2.5]]
>>>
```

### Edit:

Or, if list comprehension is too confusing, you can just change it to nested `for` loops:

```
for i in items:
    for j in items:
        if i != x or j != y:
            cp.append([i, j])
```

This runs as:

```
>>> x = 1.5
>>> y = 1.5
>>> items = [x-1, x, x+1]
>>> cp = []
>>> for i in items:
...     for j in items:
...         if i != x or j != y:
...             cp.append([i, j])
... 
>>> items = cp
>>> items
[[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 1.5], [0.5, 2.5], [1.5, 0.5], [1.5, 2.5], [2.5, 0.5], [2.5, 1.5], [2.5, 2.5]]
>>>
```

Comment: Would there be an easier way to do this? I haven't read up about list comprehension.

Comment: You could write it out without list comprehension, (ie. in multiple lines with nested for loops) if that makes it easier to understand?

Comment: @user3670654 the `a` and `b` are the ones being added to the list.

Comment: Why do you need to go items = cp

Comment: @user3670654 you don't but now the results are stored in `items`. However, you can remove that and have the results be stored in `cp`.

Comment: @aj8uppal but without items = cp, items is still [x-1, x, x+1] and cp is now the list I want?

Comment: @user3670654 yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: @user3670654 if this answer helped you do you mind accepting it by clicking on the green check next to my answer? Fill disclosure: it gives you +2 reputation :)

Comment: @aj8uppal it isn't quite working properly. when i put x as 3.5 and y as 1.5

Comment: Yes, because it is creating a list of all the permutations of `[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]`. In your question, you stated that x and y are equal, which is what I designed this code to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
values = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
[[x, y] for x in values for y in values if x <> y]
```

Output:

```
[[0.5, 1.5], [0.5, 2.5], [1.5, 0.5], [1.5, 2.5], [2.5, 0.5], [2.5, 1.5]]
```

Comment: I need a list of len 8.

Comment: Your filter clause removes too much. Also, why the `<>` syntax? It's old, weird, and gone in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331419/is-the-use-of-del-bad).

To remove from a list:

```
list_to_remove = [x, y]
list_of_lists = [[0.5,0.5],[0.5,1.5],[0.5,2.5],
                [1.5,0.5],[1.5,1.5],[1.5,2.5],
                [2.5,0.5],[2.5,1.5],[2.5,2.5]]
list_of_lists.remove(list_to_remove)
```

Keep in mind that this will raise an exception if `list_to_remove` is not in `list_of_lists`. To catch this, you need:

```
list_to_remove = [x, y]
list_of_lists = [[0.5,0.5],[0.5,1.5],[0.5,2.5],
                [1.5,0.5],[1.5,1.5],[1.5,2.5],
                [2.5,0.5],[2.5,1.5],[2.5,2.5]]

try:
    list_of_lists.remove(list_to_remove)
except:
    print "{0} is not in list_of_lists".format(str(list_to_remove))
```

Comment: I don't need to remove the entry. I need a list created with all those numbers according to x and y. [x,y] can be removed later.

Comment: What do you mean 'according to x and y'? Does this question have anything to do with removing from the list?

Comment: I don't need anything removed, I need the list created. I can't figure out an algorithm to create a list like that.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your question. Perhaps it needs to be rephrased?